# Working with foreign symbols in python

Tags: python, parsing, utf-8, ascii, symbols

I'm parsing a JSON feed in Python and it contains this  character, causing it not to validate.

Is there a way to handle these symbols? Can they be converted or is they're a tidy way to remove them?

I don't even know what this symbol is called or what causes them, otherwise I would research it myself.

EDIT: Stackover Flow is stripping the character so here:
http://files.getdropbox.com/u/194177/symbol.jpg

It's that [?] symbol in "Classic 80s"

Comment: A code snippet and your Python version are probably both relevant here. Bonus points if you know the encoding of your JSON feed.

Comment: JSON should be in one of the Unicode encodings, UTF-8, UTF-16 (BE or LE), or UTF-32 (BE or LE) <http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt>. It might be that your producer is instead sending it in ISO-8859-1 or windows-1252. You might be able to read the file as the 'wrong' encoding and fix it before parsing it.

Answer (score 1):

That probably means the text you have is in some sort of encoding, and you need to figure out what encoding, and convert it to Unicode with a thetext.decode('encoding') call.

I not sure, but it could possibly be the [?] character, meaning that the display you have there also doesn't know how to display it. That would probably mean that the data you have is incorrect, and that there is a character in there that doesn't exist in the encoding that you are supposed to use. To handle that you call the decode like this: thetext.decode('encoding', 'ignore'). There are other options than ignore, like "replace", "xmlcharrefreplace" and more.

Answer (score 0):

JSON must be encoded in one of UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32. If a JSON file contains bytes which are illegal in its current encoding, it is garbage.

If you don't know which encoding it's using, you can try parsing using my [jsonlib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonlib) library, which includes an encoding-detector. JSON parsed using `jsonlib` will be provided to the programmer as Unicode strings, so you don't have to worry about encoding at all.